# SQL Query Multiple LIKE

Tags: mysql

currently I'm making something.

```
using (var IDatabaseQuery = Lightningbolt.GetDatabaseManager().CreateQueryObject())
        {
            IDatabaseQuery.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM catalogue_baseitems WHERE name LIKE '%hc2_%' OR name LIKE '%hc3_';");
            data = IDatabaseQuery.FetchTable();
        }
```

That's what I use, I want to get all the items beginning with hc2_ and hc3_, however, I only get the items starting with hc2_. In the SQL contains also items starting with hc3_ but it doesn't show while executing the query. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want items *beginning* with `hc2_` or `hc3_`, you need to make two changes:

1. Don't use the `%` at the beginning, and
2. Escape the underscore because it masks to "any one character"

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM catalogue_baseitems WHERE name LIKE 'hc2\_%' OR name LIKE 'hc3\_%'
```

Note that `%hc2_%` will match any of the following examples:

- `abchc2X` (because of the leading `%` and the underscore will match the `X`)
- `hc23` (because underscore will match the `3`)
- ... and so on

Answer (score 1):

You want result which contains `hc2_` and `hc3_` at the beginning then you need to use clause like this `'hc2_%'` or `hc3_%`.

You are getting results for hc2_ because you are using `'%hc2_%'`, this return any string which contains `hc2_` anywhere in the string.

Change your query to this

```
IDatabaseQuery.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM catalogue_baseitems WHERE name LIKE 'hc2\_%' OR name LIKE 'hc3\_%';");
```

and don't forgot about `underscore(_)`, this is a [wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) character.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second percent sign: `'%hc3_%'`

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. I did some dirty quick work so I must've forgotten the second percent sign.